# Testing Windows filesystem driver kernel module in AZURE CI?

Tags: azure, winapi, azure-devops

Does anyone know whether it is possible to install a self-compiled Win32 64bit filesystem kernel module in the AZURE CI, reboot the CI machine and test the filesystem module  ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have self-hosted agents running a virtual machine of a custom image you create.

To create the image, follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-use-custom-image-powershell):

1. create an Azure virtual machine
2. install the kernel module
3. create the image definition
4. create the image version
5. create the scale set with the image you've just created

*The exact steps are shown in the guide.*

Now you create the Azure DevOps Agent Pool with that scale set. ([guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#create-the-scale-set-agent-pool))

Remember that to use the said agent pool, you need to define it in your pipeline yaml: `pool: NameOfYourAgentPool`.